# Why do these two rectangles not coincide?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Here is the code with tikz:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=.8mm, y=30mm][remember picture]
\tikzstyle{reverseclip}=[insert path={
  (current page.north east) --
  (current page.south east) --
  (current page.south west) --
  (current page.north west) --
  (current page.north east)}
]
\coordinate (lowerleft) at (-2mm, 2mm);
\coordinate (upperright) at (120, 2.6);

    % \input{pts}
% \path [fill=orange, draw=orange] (lowerleft) rectangle (upperright);
\fill [orange] (lowerleft) rectangle (upperright);

\begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
\path  [clip] (20, 1) circle [radius=2mm] [reverseclip];
\path  [clip] (30, 1.5) circle [radius=2mm] [reverseclip];
\path  [clip] (40, 1.3) circle [radius=2mm] [reverseclip];
\end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}

% \path [fill=white, draw=white] (lowerleft) rectangle (upperright);
\fill [white] (lowerleft) rectangle (upperright);
% \draw [help lines, opacity=.2] (lowerleft) grid (upperright);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

I would expect the second retangle to completely cover the first except for the 3 round spots.

Comment: The bounding box changes.

Comment: how can this be fixed?

Comment: With `[x=.8mm, y=30mm,remember picture]` instead of `[x=.8mm, y=30mm][remember picture]` (_and with two compilations_), the result seems correct...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[remember picture]` option is valid only for the `tikzpicture` environment. So, you must put it in the options of the `tikzpicture` environment:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=.8mm, y=30mm,remember picture]
```

The result (after *two* compilations):

[image]

The complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=.8mm, y=30mm,remember picture]
\tikzstyle{reverseclip}=[insert path={
  (current page.north east) --
  (current page.south east) --
  (current page.south west) --
  (current page.north west) --
  (current page.north east)}
]
\coordinate (lowerleft) at (-2mm, 2mm);
\coordinate (upperright) at (120, 2.6);

    % \input{pts}
% \path [fill=orange, draw=orange] (lowerleft) rectangle (upperright);
\fill [orange] (lowerleft) rectangle (upperright);

\begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
\path  [clip] (20, 1) circle [radius=2mm] [reverseclip];
\path  [clip] (30, 1.5) circle [radius=2mm] [reverseclip];
\path  [clip] (40, 1.3) circle [radius=2mm] [reverseclip];
\end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}

% \path [fill=white, draw=white] (lowerleft) rectangle (upperright);
\fill [white] (lowerleft) rectangle (upperright);
% \draw [help lines, opacity=.2] (lowerleft) grid (upperright);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```